# Convert hex to special characters (Java)

Tags: java, encoding, hex, ascii, iso-8859-1

I need to send the length of the message in the first two bytes.

Calculated the message length and it came out to be 752 lets say i.e. 02F0 in hex. Now I need to figure the special symbol corresponding to this hex value.
For getting those I use

```
 int num1 = Integer.parseInt("F0", 16);
 char c1 = (char) num1;
```

to get -> ð
The first character is not visible there (due to the encoding), but I do get the right ones. Anyhow but when I concatenate those special characters to the final message string (in ASCII) then it changes from 02F0 to 023f (confirmed that by reading the final message in ultraedit hex view). Why is that happening? 3F is 63 in decimal and I see the same thing happening with the following code snippet as well->

```
Charset asciicharset = Charset.forName("ASCII");
Charset iso88591charset = Charset.forName("ISO-8859-1");

byte [] a = new byte[]{(byte)0x02, (byte)0xF0};

ByteBuffer inputBuffer = ByteBuffer.wrap(a);

CharBuffer data = asciicharset .decode(inputBuffer);

ByteBuffer outputBuffer = asciicharset .encode(data); --> This is where instead of 240
for F0 I get 63, in fact I tried with any value more than 63 but it always comes back to
that

byte[] outputData = outputBuffer.array();
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

Comment: Is this accurate: You need to send the length of the message as the first two 8-bit characters, but the entire message (including the length) is sent as an ASCII string?

Comment: OK - you know that Java strings are 16-byte Unicode, and not 8-bit ASCII, correct?  You can read and write strings, and translate between strings and byte buffers, in whatever "encoding" you wish.  For example: `String myString = new String(myByteArray, "utf-8")`.  Or `byte[] myByteArray = myString.getBytes("utf-8")`

Comment: @GregKopff Yes, that is correct. But from the sample request messages I have, the first two bytes consist of special characters as I mentioned in my post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect your problem is not happening on the line you've commented but the *previous* line, that is:

```
 CharBuffer data = asciicharset .decode(inputBuffer);
```

ASCII characters are 7-bit, not 8-bit.  So any value greater that 127 (0x7F in hex) is not going to be in your asciicharset, so the `decode()` is probably using a default replacement.  (Note that 63 corresponds with the character '?', which makes sense as a default replacement.)

UPDATE:  From the comment threads above and below, now that I understand a bit more about what you're trying to do, I would suggest not using a Charset at all (as none of the standard named encodings there will work for any/all combinations of 2 bytes you might have for the length, even UTF-16 has reserved values for example).  Instead, I would suggest just using a byte buffer and only trying to convert to a string *after* you have stripped the initial length bytes from this.

Comment: My bad, I corrected my comment. That is precisely where I see the 63 in the outputbuffer. If I use UTF-8 instead of ASCII there, I still get the same result..i.e. 63

Comment: when you say "if I use UTF-8 instead of ASCII there..." do you mean in *both* the `encode()` and the `decode()` lines?

Comment: Yes, I simply replace ASCII with UTF-8 in     Charset asciicharset = Charset.forName("ASCII");

Comment: However using the other method i.e. typecasting to char, I do get the right result but when i combine that with the rest of the ASCII message string, I again get the incorrect value in the second byte of the message length.

Comment: @highflyer (Re your UTF-8 comment.)  That's probably because the value(s) you are trying either have 10... for the upper two bits, which is illegal in UTF-8 for the first byte, or specify a multi-byte character with no additional valid UTF-8 bytes.  Did the ISO-8859-1 charset work differently?

Comment: @highflyer (Re your typecasting comment.) That's probably because the typecast uses 16-bit chars, which should be fine with the values you are trying.  However, depending on how you "combine that with the rest of the ASCII message string", at that point, it could be trying to convert each of those two bytes into 7-bit ASCII characters.

Comment: I was assuming the default encoding would be UTF-8 so was trying to convert from that to ISO, but I lose the value due to certain UTF-8 limitation as per what you think. So I am not sure how to get them in ISO in the first place when the default encoding is UTF-8 and there is no way to convert to ISO-8859-1 using bytebuffers?  Not sure why I see the char typecast work to get the correct values and then fail later upon concatenation either..

Comment: No, it's UTF-16 by default.  (edited my response above too since Stack Overflow is telling me not to keep adding comments like this)

Comment: Seems to have helped, I can get the correct string now ,it probably was converting those 2 bytes to 7-bit ASCII as you had suggested. But when I write that string to a file, it again gets messed up? Trying using BUfferredWriter and specifying the encoding as well but even that did not help. (02 E3) is what it should be, but 02 A3 C3 is what I get upon writing to a text file. Not sure where that extra byte comes from either.